# no permission to write on mongodb data rsync

Tags: mongodb, openshift

ran this command:

```
oc rsync local/path/to/mongodump <mongodb_pod_name>:/var/lib/mongodb/data
```

got this output:

```
sent 31,825,902 bytes  received 273 bytes  1,720,333.78 bytes/sec
total size is 31,817,949  speedup is 1.00
rsync: failed to set permissions on "/var/lib/mongodb/data/." (in root): 
Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: failed to modify permissions on "/var/lib/mongodb/data/." (in root): 
Operation not permitted (1)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) 
(code 23) at main.c(1165) [sender=3.1.1]
error: exit status 23
```

and when I try to run

`$ oc rsh <mongodb_pod>
$ cd /var/lib/mongodb/data/mongodump`

I get permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
oc rsync --no-perms
```

See example tutorial about transferring files in and out of containers at:

- https://learn.openshift.com/

It mentions the need for that option for certain cases.

Since it is a dump file which I am presuming you will then load into mongodb, may be better to copy it into `/tmp` and then load mongodb with it from there. Then you will not need to delete it when done as restart of container will see files in `/tmp` thrown away.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your solution but no success.
Got error:
`Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:49420 -> 48223 
Forwarding from [::1]:49420 -> 48223
Handling connection for 49420
sending incremental file list
rsync: change_dir#1 "/var/lib/mongodb/data/temp" (in root) failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(544) [Receiver=3.0.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (194 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.1]
error: exit status 12 `

Comment: How are you deploying mongodb? Are you using a so called official mongodb image on Docker Hub. Images on Docker Hub often will not work as they expect you to be running the container as ``root``. You should use the ``mongodb-persistent`` template in the OpenShift web console catalog when you select ``Add to Project``.

Comment: I selected the mongo-persistent option, do I need to change something on the template?

Comment: Did you try the suggestion of copying it to ``/tmp`` rather than under ``/var/lib/mongodb/data``? Can you restore it from ``/tmp``?

Comment: sorry for the delay
I tried the /tmp and the --no-perms but it still does not work.
I am sending the bolao directory to /tmp and it works but then when I try to access the .tar.gz file it does not work.
I also tired copying the extract folder straight to /temp and when I try to restore the bolao folder has permission denied and the mongorestore fails

Comment: What do you mean by access the ``.tar.gz`` file? Does the ``tar`` file use relative paths, or has it perhaps got absolute paths in it, mean if you try and unpack it, it will want to write to directories you don't have permissions on. What do you get when run ``tar tvf`` on tar, and not try and extract it?